# Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: forbidden

Tags: ios, afnetworking

Can anyone help me to resolve below error

--> Getting error while using "Delete" method in AFNetworking 2.5

```
Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: forbidden (403)" UserInfo=0x7fec59455ac0

com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 
0x7fec59458aa0> {
 URL: http://server.net:8081/api?JobId=4&UserId=13&X-API-KEY=89823424323432424khk234kj34kj235jk 
} 

{ 
    status code: 403, headers 
    {
        Connection = "Keep-Alive";
        "Content-Length" = 43;
        "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        Date = "Tue, 17 Mar 2015 13:33:57 GMT";
        "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100";
        Server = "Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.15";
            "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.5.15";
    }
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that if my phone clock was out of sync... It wouldn't allow me to update ... Maybe check that your phone is set to the right time "auto zone" and see if that works... That worked for me

Refrence URL: https://community.fitbit.com/t5/Charge-HR/Can-t-set-up-error-Forbidden-403/td-p/1053680